# Trying to get this Twig (Symfony2) function extension to register

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm getting an error:
"twig extension FatalErrorException: Error: Class Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig not found in app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php"

I've cleared the cache but this does nothing.

I'm just trying to test setting it up and then I can put in all my logic.

--

A file named MyTwigExtensions.php

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig;

class MyTwigExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions() {    
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('link', 'generate_link')
        );
    }

    public function generate_link($params) {

        return "THE-LINK-HERE";

    }

    public function getName() {

        return "link";

    }

}
```

In services.yml

```
services:
  my_extension.twig.extension:
    class: Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enter fully qualified name of the extension class.

```
services:
  my_extension.twig.extension:
    class: Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig\MyTwigExtensions # <--- here
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just gives the same error message. There must be something else wrong. Thanks

Comment: Is the - { name: twig.extension } part correct? Not sure where this relates to.

Comment: Ok, sorted that (typo), now it says Twig_SimpleFunction not found, so I suppose I need to reference that somehow.

Comment: You forgot to add use statement `use Twig_SimpleFunction` or just replace `new Twig_SimpleFunction` with `new \Twig_SimpleFunction` in the extension class.

Comment: The example has an error: Twig_SimpleFunction('link', 'generate_link') will search for a standalone function `generate_link`, and it seems like the asker wanted to call the class method, which would be array($this, 'generate_link') instead of `generate_link`.

Answer (score 1):

for service reprensetation format is sth like this. addArrowInCode below is the name of the method used in twig:

```
twig.extension.addArrowInCode:
       class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AddArrowInCodeExtension
       tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
```

and for this extension you should have like...

```
class AddArrowInCodeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    function addArrowInCodeFilter($code, $separator = '&rArr;')
    {
        // do sth setting final

        return $final;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a list of filters to add to the existing list.
     *
     * @return array An array of filters
     */
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'addArrowInCode' => new Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'addArrowInCodeFilter', array('needs_environment' => false)),
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'addArrowInCode';
    }
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: Twig_Filter_Method is [deprecated](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/deprecated.html) and will be removed in 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code.

```
namespace Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig;

class MyTwigExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{

    public function getFunctions() {    
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFunction('link', array($this, 'generate_link')) // <== changed here
        );
    }

    public function generate_link($params) {

        return "THE-LINK-HERE";

    }

    public function getName() {

        return "link";

    }

}
```

In services.yml

```
services:
  my_extension.twig.extension:
    class: Acme\Bundle\MyBundle\Twig\MyTwigExtensions # <== changed here
    arguments: []
    tags:
      - { name: twig.extension }
```